# How to replace wiredep injected code in production build?

Tags: automation, gruntjs, bower, grunt-wiredep

I am using bower for package management.
Also for automatically putting bower components to HTML I am using grunt-wiredep.
I got both of them integrated into my project and working well.

For the production server, I want to minify and concat the bower components and put the path of this new file to the my HTML. I use bower_concat for concatenating the minified files.

But how will I replace wiredep script tags with this concatenated script tag?
Is there any automated way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got an answer, putting here for others.

We can use the grunt-processhtml plugin.

```html
<!-- build:js js/third-party.min.js -->
<!-- bower:js --> 
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- /build -->
```

if we put this in the html files, wiredep will fill the bower dependencies and processhtml will replace it with js/third-party.min.js